# Which has a faster load time drawing SVG or requesting for sprite images?

Tags: html, css, performance, svg, sprite

For specific example, drawing a basic shape and icon that is used in different parts of the site in different colors. Should I use svg or sprites?

But asking if there is a standard answer for this.

Comment: That would depend in the SVG or image.

Comment: What do you mean by that? In what instances would svg/sprites be faster than the other?

Comment: What is the byte size...as I said, it all depends. Some SVGs are bigger than their corresponding images.

Comment: How about inline svg?

Answer (score 2):

Using SVGs has great advantages over using a sprite, especially when implemented correctly. SVGs have good compatibility among all browsers.

- An SVG is a vector shape that can be infinitely zoomed-in, while you must have several sprites for different density displays - as a sidenote, having just one sprite of great resolution and then making it smaller using background-size doesn't scale well in all browsers leaving artifacts.
- SVG sprites can be used inline, reducing HTTP calls - depending on the language/framework you are using, an SVG can be turned inline using plugins/addons - in ember for example.
- You haven't specified what kind of shapes you are talking about, but if we are talking about single-color shapes then you can use a tool like icomoon to import all your SVG files into one Icon font file. So you have one HTTP call to get the font, like you would have with a sprite. As an added bonus an icon's color can be changed using the CSS `color` property; so with just one icon you can have multiple iterations of different colors with CSS as opposed to sprites, where you would have to design different iterations one be one before implementing them into a sprite.

Performance wise, I think these days it's not important unless we are talking about hundreds of SVGs compared to an image sprite. Even if it is slower, it would only be on 'paper' and the difference would not be identifiable to the user.